# IPN Paypal...where is the IPN to add in dev portal ??...not the IPN SIMULATOR

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

i tested the ipn simulator and works perfectly.My question is how or where to activate the ipn in the sandbox ?

I can't find it anywhere to add the address to work with test transaction.

From the dashboard from where can i find the ipn to be added ? Please?

I'm new to paypal, and I'm finding it difficult to understand how it works.I've done a lot of research but still have some questions.

Answer (score 0):

Log in to the sandbox seller account you're using at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com. Go to Profile (upper right) > My selling tools (left) > Instant payment notifications (in list) Update.

Comment: OMG thanks man!! I totally didn't know there was a sanbox for account also.Now everything is working like a charm :) Still don't understand why there is also webhooks though. With IPN i get all info i need.

Comment: No problem. Yeah PayPal isn't the clearest, and there's a lot of overlap.